# Download file with CGI C++

Tags: c++, cgi, download, save-as

I have one page that shows links, and I have some text data. How can I make using C++ CGI that by clicking on hyperlink "Save As" dialog will appear and certain amount of my text will be saved with user-defined path and name to the file on the users filesystem.

Actually, main question is how to show "Save as" dialog. After it, I think, everything will be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set an appropriate content-type header and then output the file.

The browser takes care of the rest. Any file type it doesn't recognize causes the `Save as` dialog to be displayed.

Comment: And can you tell me what is optimal size of blocks to split file into, 'cos it can be too large to send it at once? I tried to google something like "optimal html block size" but yet didn't find the answer

Comment: Why do you assume that there is a single size that is *always* optimal? :) And you should probably replace html with http in your google query ;)

Comment: not, I don't assume that there is silver bullet =) But I have to choose some block size, and I want it to be not just magic number(first my idea war 2014 bytes), but I can't find any info to base on :( "http block size" on google also didn't help.

Comment: Well, I have no clue. But you can send much bigger chunks than that easily

Answer (score 2):

They key to forcing the "Save as" dialog with a MIME type the browser can display is the [Content-Disposition header](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519).

Comment: And can you tell me what is optimal size of blocks to split file into, 'cos it can be too large to send it at once? I tried to google something like "optimal html block size" but yet didn't find the answer